# does task.delay infinite code after it executed?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Just a quick question. We're having some misunderstanding here.

for simplicity some code is removed:

```
public async Task ConsumeAsync<T>(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
 _logger.LogInformation("consume async");

 await Task.Delay(Timeout.Inifite, cancellationToken);

      _logger.LogInformation("cancelled");
}
```

Should the last logline be logged or not when a cancel is requested?

Comment: trying to get it to work with: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6CIwch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should the last logline be logged or not when a cancel is requested?

No, because the task returned by `Task.Delay` will be faulted, as is normal when a task is cancelled.

Comment: ahhh, so I misunderstood that one... would a try catch (i know i know, ugly) but would that supress it and continue the code?
Or would a `while(!token.iscancelrequested)` be a better approach?

Comment: @RoelantM: I'd find that confusing as a caller, to be honest. If I pass in a cancellation token, I don't expect code that could easily use it to just ignore it. If you have cleanup code, that's fine, and should be in a finally block - but I would think carefully before using a cancellation token just as a wait of ending a waiting period. Maybe use a `SemaphoreSlim` or something similar instead.

Comment: agreed, it is for cleanup code, but just wanted to know if it would work. .net core gives a cancellationtoken as parameters when the app stops. So this is my option. When you say in a finally block, the code for task.delay in the try and the cleanup code in the finally block, or something else.. ?

Comment: @RoelantM: Yes, exactly that - that's what finally blocks are for, after all.

Comment: last one: does a while loop but finish? or does that one to fault?

Comment: @RoelantM: Sorry, I can't parse your question... but it sounds like something you should probably be able to test for yourself.